# How to pick random values from dictionary and assign it to the list

Tags: list, file-io, dictionary, random

I have 2 dictionaries (filled by data imported from xml-spreadsheet with few nested foreach loops)
Example Excel-xml looks like this:
[image]

```
Dictionary<string, string> sheet3 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, List <KeyValuePair<string,string>>> sheet4 = new Dictionary
                                  <string, List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>();
```

each of them contains:

```
sheet3.Add(situation, succession)
sheet4.Add(srcSituation, new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>());
sheet4[srcSituation].Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(dstSituation, command));
```

In Sheet4 I can see some kind of "order". Sheet3 shows situation and what this situation feels, looks like. In Sheet4 I have order, You can see, that 1st is training, then it goes to hungry state, then hungry goes to being tired, after that, tired goes to awakening. Each of dstSituation has "command" need to be done between srcSituation and dstSituation in order for it to happen.

I want to pick random "dstSituation" from "sheet4" and write "command" into a txt file. Then look for "situation" == "dstSituation" and add "succession" string into the same txt file. Next I would start the whole thing again, but assuming that possible to pick dstSituation" is where "srcSituation" is only == to previously picked "dstSituation". And so on and so on..
Purspose of this is, once I get more "situations" there will be more srcSituation->dstSituation and ofc in Sheet4 there will be much more same srcSituation going into different dstSituation. 
Imagine this as a map where there is no 1 route to achieve some goal, but there can be randomized route. I have no clue how to write it, cause it's mostly loops operating on dictionaries and lists and I have no clue how to construct proper syntax.

Comment: Just generate random int, and then use `Dictionary.ElementAt(int);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet.

```
......Codes before

Random rnd = new Random();
int randomValue = rnd.Next(0, sheet3.Count-1);
var result = sheet3.ElementAt(randomValue);
/*
 * Your code here
 */
```